# Change border width of label in custom UICollectionCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have custom `UICollectionViewCell` and I have placed 2 `UILabels` in it. Now I want to change the  `borderRadius` and `borderWidth` of the labels in it. Can anyone tell me how to do this?
I am doing in this way, but nothing is happening:

```
    self.titleLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    self.titleLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

I am putting these two lines in `initWithFrame` method.

Comment: Are you sure, `self.titleLabel` doesn't return nil?

Comment: Did you remember to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and link to it?

Comment: @ValentinShamardin yes

Comment: @ValentinShamardin what initwithcoder method does? do i have to place the same code in it. How to change something in customXib?

Comment: @SaurabhGulia, show please, how do you create titleLabel

Comment: @GadMarkovits why i should add this.. i am not using any animation.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin i have customCell with.xib. i just simply drag n dropped a label on it.

Comment: did you connected `IBOutlet` of `UILabel`?

Comment: @SaurabhGulia, if you use xib, why do you use initWithFrame? Try to set border in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: @SaurabhGulia `CALayer` which `borderWidth` is in, is part of the `QuartzCore` framework

Comment: @ValentinShamardin thanks problem solved.. i was thinking of this. Is this the only way.. can't i change its border radius in custom class of custom cell? If it is then tell this also?

Comment: @SaurabhGulia, when I want to customize cell, I create a subclass and make all what I want. And I don't use IB, only code

Comment: @ValentinShamardin in which function you actually draw your custom ui objects.

Comment: @SaurabhGulia, I add subviews in `init` and set frames for subviews in `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the borderWidth of UILabel inside means why you are using

```
self.titleLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
```

Instead of this you can directly use the label name like,

```
yourLabel1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
yourLabel2.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
```

Like wise you can change the borderRadius also.

Answer (score 0):

With the following line added the border should appear:

```
self.titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```